# Find number of digits not divisible by X in 100th row of Pascal's Triangle

Tags: c#, algorithm, logic, pascals-triangle

I need to find out the number of digits which are not divisible by a number x in the 100th row of Pascal's triangle.

The algorithm I applied in order to find this is: since Pascal's triangle is powers of 11 from the second row on, the nth row can be found by 11^(n-1) and can easily be checked for which digits are not divisible by x.

How do I find this out for large numbers when n is equal to 99 or 100? Is there any other algorithm that can be applied to find this?

Comment: Your second sentence is very difficult to follow.  You should break it into more than one sentence, or at least add some punctuation.

Comment: Can you write an algorithm to calculate the pascal's triangle manually instead of using the digits of 11^(n-1) then you can iterate over each digit instead of using a large number which will overflow in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly calculate values of pascal's triangle using factorials (n!/(n-k+1)!(k-1)! nth row, kth value). You can start with k=1, incrementally calculate binomial coefficient and in  n/2 steps you can find the number not divisible by x.

choose(n,k+1) = choose(n,k)*(n-k+1)/k where choose(n,k) = (n!/(n-k+1)!(k-1)!

Comment: the first value of second row is 1 but using the formula u mentioned n!/(n-k)!k! gives 2 which is wrong

Comment: @Jay indexing problem. Typically k starts with 0. See my updated answer with k starting from 1.

Comment: still its not working......third row of pascal's triangle is 1 2 1.Now as per your formula in order to find out second element of third row,n=3 and k=2 so 3!/(3-2+1)!(2-1)! gives 3 but its 2

Comment: Replace n with n-1 everywhere. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle and try to understand the relation between pascal's triangle and binomial coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need exact values of 100th line of the triangle. It's OK to calculate `value mod x`. Just build the triangle as usual, but apply modulus operation everywhere - you will not need big numbers.